# SQL Server subquery collation conflict

Tags: sql, collation, sql-server-2014-express

My server is   Latin1_General_CI_AS

My database is Latin1_General_CI_AS

My table is    Latin1_General_CI_AS

My column is   Latin1_General_CI_AS

My query is:

```
SELECT Product, [Bradken Part Number], Drawing,
   (SELECT TOP (1) Location FROM dbo.Events_Table AS e WHERE
   (Product = dbo.JobSummaryView1.Product) 
   ORDER BY DateTime1 DESC) AS Expr1
FROM dbo.JobSummaryView1
```

But when I run this query it says there is a collation confilct between SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS and Latin1_General_CI_AS !

How can that be?
I'm guessing the subquery is using SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS but why?

I know I could fix it by specifying collations in the SELECT, but I'd rather prevent it from happening.

I am using SQL Server Express 2014

Comment: Even the tempdb system database says it is Latin1_General_CI_AS.

Comment: Seems like your db design has some collation inconsistency.

Answer (score 2):

try this.

```
...WHERE fieldname COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT = otherfieldname COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
```

Comment: Yes I know I can do that. My question is why would I have to if everything is set to the same collation to start with?

Comment: Collations are needed and used when ordering and comparing strings. You can check what collations each column in your table(s) has by using this query: SELECT col.name, col.collation_name FROM sys.columns col
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('YourTableName')

Comment: **From review queue**: May I request you to please add some context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.

Comment: @Treva26 thanks, this also works for the following:

`WHERE fieldname IN (SELECT fieldname FROM other_table)`

Answer (score 0):

Ah sorry my bad..

The View that is being joined relates to a different database that is actually SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

I added COLLATE in that view and now dont need any COLLATES in the query I posted.

Sorry :$

Answer (score 0):

**Answer**

If you can diagnose the view.  The conditions **"Product = dbo.JobSummaryView1.Product"** must be having separate collation applied.

Comment: @treva26 Please check.